# Do Core Computer Programs Have To Function By Powers Of 2?

Tags: computer-architecture, history

As an example, the sRGB Gamut is 256 x 256 x 256 (all powers of 2). I'm aware that computers are generally binary. However, is it simply a matter of simplicity that sRGB was made this way, or was it ESSENTIAL? After all, it probably could've safely provided just as many detectable colors with 192 X 192 X 192.

Comment: How does your question relate to mathematical and quadratic programming?

Comment: "I'm aware that computers are generally binary." -- Are you aware of *larger* structures?

Comment: I don't understand your last sentence. Do you mean that not all colors in 3-byte scheme are detectable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First it is true that no all computers binary, some [ternary computers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_computer) were built. It just turns out that binary is simpler. Now binart computers do not all work on bytes (or rather octet=8-bit). Simple examples include DSP with [18-bit words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/18-bit). Still today 24-bit words DSP are very common. The take away is that even though almost all architectures are binary, what is the simplest unit to work with depends on the architecture, it can be 8-bit, 16-bit, 18-bit, 24-bit, etc. It is true that most memories have a word size that is a power of 2 because most architectures are like this, not because it is simpler. Finally, the range chosen for particular encodings like sRGB is most often a compromise between precision and simplicity. When it comes to encoding audio and video, people usually do not care about have multiple of 8-bit. Many LCD panels encode pixels with 18 bits because it corresponds to what they can actually display, thus why waste wires? Architecture usually provide special hardware instruction to help with decoding, so working on bits instead of bytes is not really an issue.

Comment: Great explanation and examples, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is not essential. Most computers can handle no data smaller than a byte without extra effort (i.e. the memory is addressed by byte, not by bit). Hence there is generally no point in using less than a byte for anything, unless you're in a situation where memory consumption is crucial, such as network communication.

Comment: Afaik, no modern computer even has byte-adressable memory. (Maybe x86 has some wicked aliases, though?)

Comment: You might be right.